# Multiple executors per worker using YARN and Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, executors

At my company we've cobbled together a very heterogeneous YARN + Spark cluster using a combination of old and new machines. Since the stats of the individual machines vary wildly I'd like to be able to launch multiple executors on the larger machines. Setting `--num-executors` higher than the number of machines in the cluster does not work. Is there some other setting I need to change to enable this or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the --executor-cores option.  This should be ~4 for good performance:
http://www.datarpm.com/resources/achieving-optimal-performance-with-apache-spark1-5/

This'll spin up one executor on a 4 core machine, and 4 executors a 16 core machine.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I'm setting `--executor-cores` to 2 due to memory constraints, and I'm still only getting a single executor on all the machines, including the one with 32 cores.

Comment: Can you post your spark conf in your question?  This would help us debug.